# Large Uploads in Django

Tags: python, django, file-upload, cookiecutter-django

I am working on a cookiecutter-django project that requires users to be able to upload files in the .5-1gb size range. From what I understand when uploading files that are larger then 2.5Mbs django uses the `TemporaryFileUploadHandler` to first upload the file to the tmp directory and then to then transfer them to the media directory. However when I try to upload a larger file my site just hangs, I don't see any files come into the tmp directory, and I see no errors in the logs.

Is there some setting I need to turn on to instruct django to use the `TemporaryFileUploadHandler`? Or is there some way to possibly figure out where the site might be getting hung up? I am currently building out this project locally so I have full control over my environment.

I am using Python 3.4.5 and django 1.10

### UPDATE 1

I have tested uploading files of 5mb, 10mb, 20mb, and 30mb they all upload fine. The file I am having issues with is 873mb.

## UPDATE 2

After more debugging I have found that when up loading a large file to my site it gets as far as the get_form method on my view class. After that I am not sure what is called. I have been slowly adding logs at each step in the hopes of figuring out where it is stuck.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? `413: Entity too large to process`?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I don't see any error message at all. The site just hangs.

Comment: Okay. See for eg. nginx allows by default only 10mb of uploads which can be increased via changing its configuration. You will have to figure out if there are any set of restrictions on webserver to limit file upload size.

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar I am not using nginx as a server, right now I am just using the built in for development, using ./mange.py runserver. Also I have been able to upload files of up to 30mb, its just when i ramp up to 800mb that I have problems.